# Is it possible to use Danish characters for facebook login and API on a website?

Tags: facebook, special-characters, url-encoding

As far as I can tell, Facebook will not accept my attempt using and URL that contains danish native letters.

( denmark has 3 native letters only used in Denmark )

Does facebook allow URL's with foreign characters like that at all ?

Comment: URL's (whether FB or not) cannot have anything other than the basic characters.

Comment: Where do these danish characters appear? In the domain part of the URL, in the path component, …? And where and how does the problem manifest itself?

Comment: my site URL is ohøi.dk .. basic url processing renders that as this: http://ohi-8cb.dk

Comment: however.. visiting "http://ohi-8cb.dk" will not land you on my site. so i am guessing that my native characters are not supported at all. any computer in denmark, that has the UTF8 encoding supported and can type the letter on the keyboard can access my site. it clears out every bit of spam there is. so i would love to use it. but if facebook connect is not supported using these native characters, i must think of something else. the problem is that when creating the app, it tells me: Error
App Domains: http://ohi-8cb.dk is not a valid domain.

Comment: That’s not the punycode version of your domain name – http://xn--ohi-1na.dk/ is.

Comment: oh my.. you are right. thanks for pointing that out. however, even when using "http://xn--ohi-1na.dk" i still get: "Error
App Domains: http://xn--ohi-1na.dk is not a valid domain." when trying to create an app

Comment: I’m not able to reproduce that problem – when I go into the settings of one of my apps, I can put xn--ohi-1na.dk into „app domain“ without problems (after I put it into „website address” to, but that’s a general requirement for setting an app domain) – saves the changes without any error message.

Comment: just one thing. I am not sure if its just an editing error in your last comment. You are having a `"` (double quote) in the end of the url.